# Request body for Google drive image upload api

Tags: google-drive-api

I have Base64 string of image now i want to upload this to drive using google drive REST api. But i am not sure about the format of request body. Could you please any one help we on this?
Not able to find any example of such.

[image]

i want to upload image in Base64 string to drive using google drive rest api, not with any packages or sdk.

Comment: In your goal, what language do you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters change the body to Raw json not raw text.

Then just try adding something like this

```
{
  "name": "myimage.jpg",
  "mimeType": "image/jpb"
}
```

That should get you the metadata.  Give me a minute while i See if i can find an example of how to add the actual file data.

You should be able to add that in the form data section [form data](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/#form-data)

Comment: we are trying to make this call from server side, where UI will be sending the base64 encoded string to the server side controller. Can you help with the complete post rest api request parameter requirement.

Comment: depends on your programming language.  I have samples for a number of languages.